# Does Gmail API adhere with Apple developer guidelines

Tags: ios, gmail-api

I am using Gmail API in my app which pops up a sign in window along with the option to create an gmail account. Using this account the app reads the mail of the user after authorisation. Is the usage of Gmail API in the given context adheres with apple developer guidelines

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine, I've never heard of an app getting rejected for this type of login. If your app opens safari to log in you might get rejected though,

Comment: Ok will go ahead with the implementation